# Native view inside flutter app error - cannot register plugin

Tags: android, flutter, plugins

what I was trying to achieve is to embed a native view  inside a flutter app.  Something similar to [what's explained here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-platformview-how-to-create-flutter-widgets-from-native-views-366e378115b6).

My problem is that i get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: com.example.cat_app/textview
```

So I looked up how to register plugins. I tried the following code but cannot get it to work. Doing some research it seems that from flutter 1.12+ plugins register automatically so it's not needed to register them. But my code stills give the unregistered plugin error...

The following code gives me unresolved reference registrarFor error btw

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
    WebViewPlugin.registerWith(this.registrarFor("com.yourPackageName"))
  }
}
```

I'm stuck here and I don't know what should I do to register the plugin in the recent versions of Flutter. Is there any way I can achieve what I need? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To register the custom plugin try the approach mentioned https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-views

1. For the MainActivity since it implements the `io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity` class, you will need to override the `configureFlutterEngine(...)` method
2. Include the following WebViewPlugin.registerWithV2(flutterEngine);
3. Pass the flutter engine and register as follows:

   ```
   public static void registerWithV2(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {

      BinaryMessenger _messenger = flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger();

      flutterEngine.getPlatformViewsController().getRegistry().registerViewFactory("MyViewTypeId", new CWebFactory(_messenger));
   }
   ```